# How to write the "not in" construct of T-Sql in Linq to Entities as a SubQuery?

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

The query:-

```
    select * from Product.Barcodes where Barcode='00A000000O' and  
 Barcode not in(select Barcode from Sales.SalePointItem)
```

I have tried the following, but these does not work:-

```
db.Barcodes.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Barcode.Equals(ItemBarcode) &&  
  !db.SalePointItems.Select(m=>m.Barcode).Contains(b.Barcode));

db.Barcodes.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Barcode.Equals(ItemBarcode) &&  
  !db.SalePointItems.Any(m=>m.Barcode.Equals(b.Barcode)));
```

I get the following exception on running both of above:-

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'SalePointItemModel'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Comment: What do you mean *does not work*? Are you getting the wrong result? Or is the generated SQL not what you expect? What is the generated SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var item = (from b in db.Barcodes
            where b.Barcode == ItemBarcode
            where !db.SalePointItems.Any(m => m.Barcode == b.Barcode)
            select b).SingleOrDefault();
```

Method Syntax -

```
var item = db.Barcodes.Where(b => b.Barcode == ItemBarcode)
                      .Where(b => !db.SalePointItems.Any(m => m.Barcode == b.Barcode))
                      .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I know this method, but I don't want a separate query, I wanted to run it as a subquery. See the title of the question as I have updated it.

Comment: The intent is to avoid fetching the list of barcodes into memory which the origninal t-sql does.

Comment: Actually, this works, but I was looking for extension method chains, because I usually write in that form, all my queries.

Comment: @puretechy - I added extension method way.